# Sklearn FeatureUnion Issue with Actual Union of Features in Pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two feature selection algorithms I'm running after doing a standard scalar.
One is information gain through K Best, and the other is using an extra trees classifier to get feature importances using Select from Model.

I make a pipeline.  I was using Feature Union to combine the kbest and select from model steps.  When I saw the end result, there are actually copies of some of the features in the final model.

Going back to the documentation, (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#feature-union) FeatureUnion, is really a feature concatenation.

> (A FeatureUnion has no way of checking whether two transformers might produce identical features. It only produces a union when the feature sets are disjoint, and making sure they are the caller’s responsibility.)

Is there a way to create a pipeline structure such that I can have the actual feature union results of my information gain selection and then extra trees classifier?  What's the easiest way to do this to ensure I wont have duplicate features?

One thing I'm trying is making a custom Transfomer.

```
class RemoveDuplicateColumnsTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        X=X.loc[:,~X.columns.duplicated()]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
```

But I end up with this error because I'm also using a standard scalar and the X in the transform function is interpreted as an ndarray instead of a dataframe.  so it says there is no loc attribute.